# How we can Add categories in base of main menu

Tags: wordpress, categories, elementor

I am designing website in base of Wordpress but
l can’t see the category in base of the main menu in elemenor
I created main menu but l can’t see them in elemenor

I have problem that don’t exist category in elemenor

How l can add it? Or how can I see the category in elemenor Please help me